# Como visualizar os nomes dos arquivos selecionados no file Múltiplo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá
Tenho um file multiple e gostaria de mostrar dentro dele o nome dos arquivos selecionados, tenho um código que me lista os nomes no console.log, mais como eu poderia adicionar eles dentro do próprio input type?

```js
$(".fileMultiplo").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      for (let i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++){
          console.log(input.files[i].name)
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
              <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" multiple class="custom-file-input fileMultiplo" name="uploads[]" id="customFileMultiplo" 
                data-toggle="tooltip"  title="Selecione vários arquivos" required>
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Selecione vários arquivos</label>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Selecione um ou mais de um arquivo
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Resolveria se mostrasse os nomes dentro de um **span**, e aí reposiciona-se esse **span** aonde você quer? Ou necessariamente tem que ser no **input file**?

Comment: @GutoXavier, hoje o nome do arquivo e visualizado dentro do input file, apenas 1 deles, eu poderia até mostrar em um span, mais ficaria dentro do span e dentro do input file, agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Veja se essa ideia resolve a situação:

- Criei um **span** em frente ao **input file**
- Só adiciono conteúdo à esse **span** se for selecionado mais de um arquivo.

**Segue o código**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" multiple class="custom-file-input fileMultiplo" name="uploads[]" id="customFileMultiplo" data-toggle="tooltip"  title="Selecione vários arquivos" required>
        <span id="nome"></span>
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Selecione vários arquivos</label>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Selecione um ou mais de um arquivo
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(".fileMultiplo").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      if(input.files.length > 1){
        for (let i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++){
            console.log(input.files[i].name)
            $('#nome').append(input.files[i].name);
        }
    }else{
        $('#nome').html('');
    }
  }
```